# Sort cells based on cell content

Tags: excel, isnumeric, vba

[image]

What I currently have is clients’ information (name, address, landline or mobile number), all in column A with blank cells in between, and some notes on each client on columns F & G.

What I am looking to do is move the info relevant of each client to the same row as the name (e.g. name @ A1, then address @B1, number (if landline) @ C1 (else @ C2)) and combine the notes of the client into one cell in the same row (F1 = F1 & F2).

We are talking about thousands of rows and multiple workbooks so this needs to be done through VBA.
Please find what I have tried so far below:

```
Sub SORT()
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
Dim i As Long, j As Boolean
i = 1
j = IsNumeric(ActiveCell.Range("A1"))
Do
    If j = True Then    'Check if cell content is numeric
        If ActiveCell.Range("A1") < 3000000000# Then    'Then if it's a landline
            Selection.Cut
            ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 2).Range("A1").Select 'Put it in column C
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Range("A1").Select 'Go to Address Cell
        Else
            Selection.Cut                   'If it is a mobile
            ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 3).Range("A1").Select 'Put it in column D
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Range("A1").Select 'Go to Address Cell
        End If
        Selection.Cut                   
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste                   'Put the Address to column B
        ActiveCell.Offset(4, -1).Range("A1").Select     'Go to next cell
        i = i + 4
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select      'If Check if cell content is not numeric, go to next cell
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop While i <= 100
End Sub
```

Sample File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uf9yh6fnxl54j55/SAMPLE.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Cannot use dropbox here - Could you provide a screenshot or sample "client block" that needs to be transposed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RikSportel thanks for the response. I have now added a sample screenshot. Please let me know of your thoughts on this. Thank you

Comment: Just came across this old question today.  Did you solve the problem?  Or do you still need assistance?  If so, do you want to also delete the blank rows, so the entries are contiguous?